# validating if a user entered an ip address or CIDR notation when prompted

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip-address, cidr

im using the ipaddress module in python. Here is my current scenario. we have self service portal of sorts that will promt the user to enter an IP address. We will allow this to be an individual IP like 165.136.219.5 or something like this 165.136.219.0/24. Once the have entered the data, i want my code to check and ensure its either a valid IPV4 address or a valid IPV4 CIDR.

when i do something like this code below, i get a failure that "/" isnt a valid character. Am i using the ipaddress package wrong ?

```
newIpAddress = input("Please enter the IP address for SFTP access: ")
if ipaddress.IPv4Address(newIpAddress) == True or ipaddress.IPv4Network(newIpAddress) == True:
```

Im basically grabbing input from a end user, and then I want to use an if statement basically stating so long as its either a valid IPV4 IP or a valid IPV4 CIDR then go do some tasks, then ill do some else statements that print out some verbiage about not meeting the address or network requirements.

my current code spits out the the following error:

Unexpected '/' in '165.136.219.0/24'
File "C:\Users\myname\Documents\my_Scripts\PaloAlto\sftpNew.py", line 21, in 
if ipaddress.IPv4Address(newIpAddress) == True or ipaddress.IPv4Network(newIpAddress) == True:

Comment: Slightly tangential, but can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that `ipaddress.IPv4Address()` and `ipaddress.IPv4Network()` should return a boolean-typed value? [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_address) makes explicit that these are constructors for the classes of the same name, and in no way are expected to return a boolean-typed value.

Comment: probably because im new to python and didnt think about what your saying, ill have to re-read the documentation and fill in my knowlege gaps.

Comment: so it seems im going to have to find another way to validate the IP or CIDR notation. it seems there are booleans in other objects like is_private or is_reserved or is_global but not for the ipaddress.IPv4Address() and ipaddress.IPv4Network()

Comment: Huh? How did you get to that conclusion? What about my answer below doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: i didnt see your code response previously, i guess i had not scrolled down far enough to see it my apologies, im really new to this..sorry for missing the update

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly for what i needed. I apprecaite it very much!

Comment: for what its worth im a network engineer by trade, im trying to learn to automate tasks as it pertains to my network environment which is made up of:  palo alto, nginx and aws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ipaddress` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#convenience-factory-functions) does not appear to provide any convenience methods for determinig whether a string represents a valid IPv4 address versus a valid IPv4 network versus neither a valid address or network.

However, you can build your own rudimentary functionality to check to see if one or the other throws an exception and return `true` or `false` and use it in your conditional:

```
import ipaddress
def valid_ip_or_cidr(ip):
    try:
        ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip)
        print('valid as address')
        return True
    except:
        try:
            ipaddress.IPv4Network(ip)
            print('valid as network')
            return True
        except:
            print('invalid as both an address and network')
            return False

        
valid_ip_or_cidr('192.168.1.1')
# valid as address
# True
valid_ip_or_cidr('192.168.1.0/24')
# valid as network
# True
valid_ip_or_cidr('foo')
# invalid as both an address and network
# False
```

In your context, this would be implemented in your conditional as:

```
newIpAddress = input("Please enter the IP address for SFTP access: ")
if valid_ip_or_cidr(newIpAddress):
    # code to execute if validation succeeds
```